# build a console application file explorer c++

Tags: c++, file, console, console-application

I need to make a windows console application file explorer using c++  , but I couldn't figure out how to use functions to display files nor how am I going to make it look like knowing that console application doesn't support buttons or displaying lists , specially that the project must be based on windows.h library. any tip, advice or suggestion may be helpful , thank you !

Comment: I suggest you to read about [ncurses](http://www.cs.ukzn.ac.za/~hughm/os/notes/ncurses.html). It is used to create text-based graphical applications.

Comment: You can see [ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger) or [midnight commander](http://midnight-commander.org/) as example.

Comment: @souki I'm only allowed to use the windows.h library

Comment: @TemmaniRafik oh okay, well then I suggest you to add it to your question, as well as other constraints you might have

Comment: @souki , I've edited the question , thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/list-the-files-in-a-directory-in-c.html and scroll down to method 4. There you can see a possible implementation of a read-directory function. You should store a default start path, implement some console arguments as commands, then, whenever the user writes a command (for example goUp) ,change the path accordingly (in this case, remove the last foldername), call the function, which reads the directory, again and output all files in that folder.

Comment: thank you  @ben , is there any way to display a number before each name of files or directories , so that i use that number to select the file / dir i want to open ?

Comment: You can store the number of files and folders in a directory in a int, then, when you iterate through the files and folders to print them in the console,  print a counter which increments everytime before the file or folder name. Then you can ask for an int, check if it's between 0 and the number of files and folders in the directory, and if the int is valid, append stringvec[inputNumber] to the path, so that you change the directory. Are you ok with that? If not, please just ask further!

Comment: that's exactly what I tried to do , but i couldn't print a number before each file/dir name

Comment: here is the instruction that prints file/dir names ,  std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " \n"));

Comment: Just make it in a loop and print out the counter.